# Why isn’t this newtype being given the right Read instance?

Tags: haskell, deriving, newtype

I created a `newtype` alias of the `IP` type from `Data.IP`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module IPAddress (IPAddress) where

import Data.IP (IP)
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.ToField

newtype IPAddress = IPAddress IP
    deriving (Read, Show)

instance ToField IPAddress where
    toField ip = toField $ show ip
```

(I wanted to make it an instance of `ToField` without creating an orphan instance.)

The new type doesn’t seem to support `Read` in the way it should, though. In this GHCi transcript, you can see that the given string can be interpreted as an `IP` but not as an `IPAddress`:

```
*Main IPAddress> :m + Data.IP
*Main IPAddress Data.IP> read "1.2.3.4" :: IP
1.2.3.4
*Main IPAddress Data.IP> read "1.2.3.4" :: IPAddress
IPAddress *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

The behavior is the same regardless of whether I have GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving on. Why is the `Read` instance for `IPAddress` not identical to the one for `IP`?

Comment: Give it a Show instance as well, and see what it prints as. It'll read the same way.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the instance generated by `deriving Read` will work exactly the same way as if `IPAddress` were a `data` type

Comment: @amalloy I added `IsString` to the list of derived classes and then I was able to create an `IPAddress` via `"1.2.3.4" :: IPAddress`. Calling `show` on this value gives `"IPAddress 1.2.3.4"`, and indeed `read "IPAddress 1.2.3.4" :: IPAddress` does what I want. I suppose you should turn your comment into an answer! I’d love an explanation of why I have to prepend the value with `IPAddress`, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GHC has three mechanisms for deriving typeclass instances:

- The [normal deriving mechanism](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch11.html#x18-18200011) outlined in the Haskell standard, which can derive instances for a small, predefined set of classes (`Eq`, `Ord`, `Enum`, `Bounded`, `Read`, and `Show`).

  - The set of classes that can be derived can be extended using the `DeriveFunctor`, `DeriveFoldable`, `DeriveTraversable`, and `DeriveLift` extensions, which are treated the same way as the classes listed in the standard when enabled.
- [`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.2/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#generalised-derived-instances-for-newtypes), which can derive instances that defer to instances on the wrapped type.
- [`DeriveAnyClass`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.2/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#deriving-any-other-class), which turns derived classes into empty instance declarations.

There’s a problem here. It is extremely easy to construct a scenario where more than one of the above mechanisms can be used to derive an instance, and the instances can be quite different! In your example, both ordinary deriving *and* newtype deriving could apply. If you also enabled `DeriveAnyClass`, it could apply, too.

To disambiguate, GHC uses hardcoded rules you cannot change, which it tries from top to bottom:

1. If the class can be derived using the ordinary deriving mechanism, use that.
2. If `DeriveAnyClass` is enabled, use that.
3. If `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` is enabled and the declared datatype is a newtype, use that.

Note that this means turning on `DeriveAnyClass` and `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` at the same time is effectively worthless. If anything, the bottom two rules should be swapped, but they can’t really be changed now.

In your case, since `Read` is a class for which an instance can be derived via the ordinary deriving mechanism, GHC uses that one instead of using newtype deriving, and you get the behavior you see. This is consistent with the way `Show` works, too—deriving `Show` will produce an instance that includes `IPAddress` in the output—so `Read` should follow the same format to satisfy the one law `Read` has.

It would be nice if there were some mechanism to instruct GHC to use a particular deriving mechanism, but there currently isn’t. In this case, you’ll have to write the instance by hand. Fortunately, it isn’t too hard.

Comment: "It would be nice if there were some mechanism to instruct GHC to use a particular deriving mechanism". [This is coming in GHC 8.2](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/DerivingStrategies).

Comment: @Alec Oh wow, I didn’t know about that! That’s awesome to hear, since it’s a feature I’ve wanted for a while now.