# Automatically deriving toJSON/fromJSON using the instances of the inner type of a newtype

Tags: haskell, aeson

In my code I use a lot of `newtype` declarations, like:

```
newtype PersonName = PersonName { personName :: Text }
newtype PetName = PetName { petName :: Text }
```

(In practice I use lenses to avoid the cumbersome names for the accessor functions.)

However, if I derive the instance from `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` automatically, the resulting JSON will be of the form:

```
{ "personName": "The person name" }
{ "petName": "The pet name" }
```

Is there a way to avoid the boilerplate of declaring trivial instances of `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` for the `newtype`s above, in such a way that the resulting JSON objects will be of the form:

```
"The person name"
"The pet name"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn’t this newtype being given the right Read instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175498/why-isn-t-this-newtype-being-given-the-right-read-instance)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#generalised-derived-instances-for-newtypes) to derive the instances.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype PersonName = PersonName { personName :: Text }
    deriving (ToJSON, FromJSON)
```

Comment: Would this unwrap the record as well?

Comment: No, `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` instances work exactly the same way as their underlying type. Basically `PersonName` is an abstract synonym for `Text`

Comment: Er I mean yes.  I misunderstood what "unwrap" meant

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the new deriving strategies extension, which would probably be worth using if `DeriveAnyClass` is also enabled in that module.

Answer (score 4):

I needed to set the option `unwrapUnaryRecords` to `True` when using `deriveJSON`:

```
import           Data.Aeson
import           Data.Aeson.TH
import           Data.Text            (Text)

newtype PersonName = PersonName { personName :: Text }
$(deriveJSON (defaultOptions { unwrapUnaryRecords = True }) ''InstallationId)
```